# How do I force my Android network to route port 80 network traffic to a wifi network that does not have internet access?

Tags: android, networking, retrofit, okhttp

Scenario:
(device: Pixel OS: Android 7.1.1, (also Galaxy 7, Android 7.0)

1. App is connected to a local wifi network that does not have internet access
2. Pixel phone is connected to LTE cellular data connection
3. App requests a url like http://192.168.1.1:80/test Pixel phone routes
   that request to the LTE cellular data connection, presumably because
   it has internet connectivity and my wifi network does not.

I want to force the App to make the http://192.168.1.1:80/test request on the local wifi network even if it does not have external internet capabilities.

I am using Retrofit and Okhttp, and also have tried: org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

If 192.168.1.0/24 is a locally connected network, it should be routed automatically. If not, you'll need a routing table entry, e.g. 192.168.1.0/24 -> 192.168.99.1 (if your Wifi is 192.168.99.0/24 and .1 is the router in between).

Comment: I cannot edit the routing tables for Android devices that I don't own. I need a way for my Android app work on any device it is installed on

Comment: So, 192.168.1.0/24 is a remote network? Without routing table entry there's no way it'll work.